# Load json file with object array into SQL from file

Tags: json, sql-server-2019

I have json formatted files I am trying to load into a SQL Server 2019 table. Two of the fields have object arrays that I want to load with the arrays parsed into separate rows, and without the brackets, quotes and leading/trailing spaces.

Contents of the json file look like

```
[
{
"TIN": "1234",
"clinic_name": "Acme clinic",
"specialties": [
            "Hand Surgery",
            "Orthopedic Surgery"
        ],
"languages_spoken": [
            "English",
            "Spanish"
        ],
"approval_date": "2020-02-18",
},
{
"TIN": "5678",
"clinic_name": "Elm clinic",
"specialties": [
            "Hematology &amp; Oncology",
            "Internal Medicine"
        ],
"languages_spoken": [
            "English",
            "Russian"
        ],
"approval_date": "2020-05-17",
}
]
```

The arrays load like this:
[image]

This is what I have currently:

```
 Declare @ProviderDirCO varchar (max)
SELECT @ProviderDirCO=BULKCOLUMN

FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'F:\JSON\TESTProviderDirectory.json', SINGLE_CLOB) json 
insert into [Providers].ProviderDirTest_DH
 SELECT distinct
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.TIN') as TIN,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.clinic_name') as clinic_name,
    JSON_QUERY(a.value, '$.specialties') as specialties,
    JSON_QUERY(a.value, '$.languages_spoken') as languages_spoken
    


    FROM OPENJSON(@ProviderDirCO ) as a
```

Can I get this loaded directly into a SQL table with the arrays parsed out already or does it need to get loaded into a staging table and then cleaned up from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
    Declare @ProviderDirCO varchar (max)
SELECT @ProviderDirCO=BULKCOLUMN

FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'F:\JSON\TESTProviderDirectory.json', SINGLE_CLOB) json 
insert into [Providers].[ProviderDirTest_DH]
 SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.TIN') as TIN,
    JSON_VALUE(a.value, '$.clinic_name') as clinic_name,
    b.specialties,
    c.languages_spoken



    FROM OPENJSON(@ProviderDirCO ) as a
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value, '$.specialties')
 WITH (
    specialties NVARCHAR(100) '$'
    )
 as b
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(value, '$.languages_spoken')
 WITH (
    languages_spoken NVARCHAR(100) '$'
    )
 as c
```